# Asp Net Gridview sort disapears when row edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

when I click on the line update the gridview sort of disappears and returns to its initial state. what can be? 
Below transcribe my code:

```
  private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        //Retrieve the table from the session object.
        DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            Session["TaskTable"] = dt;
            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        //CheckBox alt = GridViewLayoutProduto.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("CheckBox1") as CheckBox;
        //alt.Enabled = false;
        BindData();
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
    }

    protected void GridViewLayoutProduto_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.EditIndex = -1;
        BindData();
    }

    private void BindData()
    {
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
        GridViewLayoutProduto.DataBind();
    }
```

in the session data the datatable to stored will not be organized, how can I store in a session with the datatble sort performed.

Answer (score 0):

Try Putting this line after Sort of `GridView`

```
Session["TaskTable"] = ((DataView)gvProgramlar.DataSource).ToTable();
```

Hope this helps you!